# Media query at max-width not activating CSS styles

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

This is a general rundown of the problem I'm dealing with. I have my main CSS stylesheet and two others that have media queries.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/mainStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/smStyles.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/mdStyles.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1269px)">`

When the browser is at a width of 990px the smStyles stylesheet is being called. At 992px the mdStyles takes over.

But if the width is at 991px, the smStyles is no longer in effect and my webpage reverts to the mainStyles sheet (making the entire page look like a mess).

I've been going at this for hours and I can't figure out why it is happening.
Please let me know if there is something I am missing here. I'm viewing the widths using the Chrome inspector.

(Also, yes, I do have  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`)

Comment: The usual pattern is to use one or the other: `min-width` or `max-width`

Comment: Initially I decided to go with the "greater than/less than" check for my media queries because I wanted to keep the stylesheets isolated from one another and avoid losing track of my code from scaling using `min-width`. But on reflection I think I'm going to try doing the latter for my next project: make my main stylesheet and then tailor the webpage by going from small to large pixel width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/mdStyles.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1269px)">
```

I know it's an overlap setting min-width for mdStyles to 991, but would it work?